# How i can split array in js?

Tags: javascript, regex

How i can split string in js for result:

```
result = ["post_address", "location", "area"]
```

This is problem? Need help with `re`

```
let re = ???
let arr = "post_address[location][area]".split(re)
```

Comment: Please show an input example and expected output. You may want to look at destructuring

Comment: @mplungjan I agree. It is not clear what we are trying. I want to see the desired i/o.

Answer (score 2):

Simply split by `/\[|\]/` and the remove the *empty strings*.

```js
var output = "post_address[location][area]".split(/\[|\]/).filter((s)=>s.length > 0);

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regexp like this :

```
var re = /^(\w*)\[(\w*)\]\[(\w*)\]$/gi;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Lodash](https://lodash.com):

```js
const str = "post_address[location][area]";
const output = _.compact(_.split(str, /\[|\]/));
console.log(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is the shorter way

[image]

It is actually the same as

```
'post_address[location][area]'.split(/[^\w]+/).filter(i => i)
```

```js
console.log(
    'post_address[location][area]'.match(/(\w+)/g)
);

console.log(
    'post_address[location][area]'.split(/[^\w]+/).filter(i => i)
);
```